# Как сформировать запрос к API из условий JSON

Tags: c#, wpf, json, websocket

Есть такой пример запроса API исходя из которого select формируется условиями выбора элементов

```
{
 “cmd”: “get_data_req”, //запрос
 “devEui”: string, //название прибора
 “select”?: //условия
 {
    “date_from”?: integer, //начальная дата
    “date_to”?: integer,  //конечная дата
    “begin_index”?: integer, //с какого элемента начинается 
    “limit”?: integer, //количество данных  
 }
}
```

в js запрос выглядит следующим образом

```
var tempObj = new Object();
           tempObj.cmd = "get_data_req";
           tempObj.devEui = devEui;
           if (date_from!=undefined||date_to!=undefined||limit!=undefined) //в случае если имеются дополнительные параметры для запроса
           {
               tempObj.select = new Object();
               if (date_from!=undefined)
               {
                   tempObj.select.date_from=date_from;
               }
               if (date_to!=undefined)
               {
                   tempObj.select.date_to=date_to;
               }
               if (limit!=undefined)
               {
                   tempObj.select.limit=limit;
               }
               if (port!=undefined)
               {
                   tempObj.select.port=port;
               }
           }
           my_ws.send(JSON.stringify(tempObj));
```

мой код, msg переменная для сериализации json и получение данных с определенными условиями, условия так же могут быть нулевыми

```
var msg = new
  {
    cmd = "get_data_req",
    devEui = deviceListView.SelectedItem, 
    select = new
    {   
    date_from = Convert.ToString(DatetimeToUnix(startDate.SelectedDate.Value)),
    limit = Convert.ToInt32(limitCB.Text)
    }
  };
well.Text = limitCB.Text;
ws.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
```

Comment: `как с помощью if формировать msg` Объясните, что вы под этим понимаете?

Comment: Задача обозначена слишком кратко и непонятно. Непонятно что за API, что за msg, есть даже сомнения, что вы хотите сделать: толи по json сделать linq запрос, толи наоборот. В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: [GraphQL](https://habr.com/ru/post/326986/)

Comment: `if (condition) limit = ... else limit = null`. Сериализатор при этом настроен так, чтобы опускать null-значения. Однако, вам действительно стоит посмотрать на GraphQL.